# Accessing object fields added to model map in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my `Spring` web project, I have added a class object in to the `model map`. This is the class

```
public class ProjectDetailsBean {

    private String title;
    private String type;
    private String addedBy;
    private String status;
    private String updatedOn;
    private String relavantBranch;

    // getters and setters are here

}
```

After setting all the attributes to a `ProjectDetailsBean` object instance, I add that to the `model map` in my `controller` class.

`epb` is that instance.

```
model.addAttribute("projectDetails", epb);
```

Now I need to access the fields of `projectDetails` in a `jsp` page. Those values need to be assigned to separate input fields. I cannot figure out how to do that. Could you please tell me how to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access through **Expression language**

```
${projectDetails.title}

${projectDetails.addedBy}



....... so on
```